# CoAP over DTLS duplication of epoch and seq no

Tags: tls

I am currently looking at the DTLS overhead when running CoAP and found a strange thing.

DTLS record layer header, 13 Byte, consists of:
{
content type, 1 Byte
version        , 2 Byte
epoch          , 2 byte
seq_no        , 6 byte
length          , 2 byte
}

AES_CCM_128_8 has a tag of 8 bytes

DTLS overhead for the record layer should then be 13 byte for the record header and 8 byte for the tag, making the total overhead 21 bytes.

But when I look in wireshark, the overhead is actually 29 bytes.

The reason for this is that epoch and seq_no is included twice, once in the record header and once in the payload. i.e. the payload is
epoch + seq_no + tag + coap

This seems very strange, why duplicate this? I´m running Californium for CoAP with the Scandium plugin for DTLS.

Here is a link to a pcap file 
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01886789284371410631

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AEAD format, after the 13-byte DTLS record header you correctly describe, begins with an 8-byte **explicit nonce** (combined with implicit nonce aka 'salt' from key derivation to form the actual nonce); this **may be (epoch+)seqnum**.

Quoting https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6655 (which applies to both TLS and DTLS, remember):

> [...] The
> nonce_explicit is the "explicit" part of the nonce.  It is chosen by
> the sender and is carried in each TLS record in the
> GenericAEADCipher.nonce_explicit field.  The nonce_explicit length
> (SecurityParameters.record_iv_length) is 8 octets.  Each value of the
> nonce_explicit MUST be distinct for each distinct invocation of the
> GCM encrypt function for any fixed key.  Failure to meet this
> uniqueness requirement can significantly degrade security.  The
> nonce_explicit MAY be the 64-bit sequence number (as long as those
> values are assured to meet the distinctness requirement).

> In DTLS, the 64-bit seq_num is the 16-bit epoch concatenated with the
> 48-bit seq_num.